# Different behaviour of double to integer in different architectures and unit tests

Tags: c++, x86, arm64

I'm trying to understand how to avoid a different behaviour on different archs when working with double precision math and using integers as a way to "trunc/round" them...

Here is a minimal example that reproduces the issue...

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double a = 1690391867.3996975, b = 1690391867.4996974;
    int res = b * 1000 - a * 1000;
    std::cerr << "Result is " << res << "\n";
}
```

If I build this for intel the result is **100**, both if I run on a native machine or rosetta, both on linux and macOS (both gcc and clang), if I run it on arm64 the result is 99... both on linux or macOS (both gcc and clang).

```bash
/tmp$ g++ test.cpp
/tmp$ ./a.out 
Result is 99
/tmp$ g++ -arch x86_64 test.cpp
/tmp$ ./a.out 
Result is 100
```

I found a reliable solution if I want to have always 100 is to change the line to:

```cpp
    int res = std::round(b * 1000 - a * 1000);
```

... but I have a huge codebase where the "trick" of using a stack integer to trunc a double is used everywhere....

There is a compiler switch or something else I can use to globally catch this issue and force both architectures to behave in the same way?

Here is a table with the platform / OS that I tried and show different results:

| platform | result | platform | compiler |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| arm64 | 99 | macos | clang |
| arm64 | 99 | linux | clang |
| x86_64 | 100 | macos | clang |
| x86_64 | 100 | linux | clang |
| x86_64 | 100 | windows | mingw64 |
| x86_64 | 100 | windows | vc++ |
| x86 | 99 | windows | borland c++ |

NOTE:
I've read both:

[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
[Different floating point result with optimization enabled - compiler bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517588/different-floating-point-result-with-optimization-enabled-compiler-bug)

that has been reported as answers for my question, but the solution given there does not work in this use case.

The use case is to be able to reliably run **unit tests** both in local environments (recently we mostly use ARM64 macs) and CI (that is still based on x86_64 machines).

Comment: Floating point math is just not good enough to get exact and precise results. Different systems will behave differently, that's just an unfortunate effect that one have to live with and work around in other ways. Perhaps if you ask about the underlying problem and where you get those oddly specific values from we might be able to help you solve that in a better way?

Comment: And if you haven't read it yet, please read [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Output the result of `b * 1000 - a * 1000` to a precision of 20 on both platforms.   Also note that assigning a `double` to an `int` does truncation.

Comment: Also note comparing floating point numbers to an absolute precission is not recommended anyway. You should also compare to almost equal (and there are a lot of different strategies to select from).

Comment: The trick to catch these kind of things in time it to have unit tests and to run those on all platforms. For you this probably means putting all the lines of code with calculations into seperate functions (call those from your existing code) and then write unit tests for them. That way you can fix those functions where it is a problem.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/hvdoMoYrr <- I would not rely on this being stable on Intel either

Comment: In C++, floating point behavior is implementation defined.  Most of the platforms I use have the implementation defined behavior of IEEE 754 (ISO/IEC 60559).  Within IEEE 754, there is some wiggle room on that behavior as well depending on float environment settings (q.v. [`cfenv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cfenv)).  You should check to make sure the **fe** settings are set similiarly on all platforms.

Comment: The C++ standard specifies no requirements that ensure the consistency you seek between target platforms (unless all the platforms use *identical* floating point representations (e.g. IEEE) and relevant identical settings (e.g. rounding modes) - which is not your situation).  You either need to accept/manage some imprecision, or do calculations without involving any floating point (e.g. use integral or some fixed point representation).  Impossible to be more specific, without information on your *actual* use case (since different use cases are suited to different trade-offs).

Comment: The problem/issue here is not in the conversion from floating-point to integer: that is a process that is well-defined by the C++ Standard (assuming the result will fit into the specific integer type). Your issue is with the actual FP maths and the minor differences that has between platforms.

Comment: Try `-ffp-contract=off` to turn off fusing.  That should get consistent results on the two platforms in this particular case.

Comment: Intrestingly forcing fp-contract does the trick in this small example, but for some reason does not work properly when you switch from debug to O3 optimization level...

Comment: The problem here is to be able to have consistent results in CI and local in tests, error like this propagates badly, and I end up with some values that on ARM64 are around "3" and in x86_64 around "5", so there is no way I can build a reliable unit test that work on both.

Comment: Five stages of discovering the truth about floating point math on computers.  1) denial: "This cannot work this way!", 2) anger: "This is completely broken!", 3) bargaining: "How can I trick the compiler into making this work?", 4) depression: "I cannot trick the compiler into making this work.", and 5) acceptance: "It works good enough, for a large problem domain, as long as there are no expectations of perfect math in all cases."

Comment: If your unit tests are checking the results after catastrophic cancellation (of most of the significant bits) removes most of the precision like this, it matters a lot whether multiply+subtract gets "contracted" to remove the rounding in a temporary or not, either at run-time, or during compile-time eval which is happening here.  GCC and clang are pretty good at respecting `-ffp-contract=off`, although `-fexcess-precision=standard` vs. `fast` can also come into play.  [C++ handling of excess precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20869904)

Comment: Also [Why does this simple program compiled with gcc,-mfpmath=387, and an optimization level of -O2 or -O3 produce NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74728946)

Comment: @Eljay: 6) Understanding which things are problematic for FP math (e.g. subtracting nearby numbers), and using numerical techniques like Kahan error-compensated summation to get more precision when it's worth the effort and performance cost.  i.e. using FP math for what it really is, rather than just treating it as a randomly-error-prone approximation for real numbers.  To be fair, the latter part of this does sometimes involve learning how to tame your compiler to get strict IEEE FP math semantics when required, e.g. https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath